# Show specific comment in LESS file when compiled to CSS while keeping all other comments hidden

Tags: css, less

I wish to add a line at the top of my compiled LESS stylesheet which reads `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE`

My LESS stylesheet also contains lots of other comments which I have made 'silent' - meaning they are omitted from the compiled CSS file.

How can I get this specific comment to output yet keep all the others silent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So instead of single line less comment

```
// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
```

use block css-style less comment

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE */
```

Comment: My compiler (Koala) is also removing those on compress

Comment: @6h8j5 thats an issue with the koala compiler. less standard compiler doesnt remove it. less is designed to retain css comments

Comment: Thanks I have modified some settings and works fine.